# How do I plot data on different x-axes and scales with d3.js? And keep it linked for brushes/tooltips?

Tags: d3.js

I have the following data (mpg and hp from mtcars):

```
[{"mpg":21,"hp":110},{"mpg":21,"hp":110},{"mpg":22.8,"hp":93},{"mpg":21.4,"hp":110},{"mpg":18.7,"hp":175},{"mpg":18.1,"hp":105},{"mpg":14.3,"hp":245},{"mpg":24.4,"hp":62},{"mpg":22.8,"hp":95},{"mpg":19.2,"hp":123},{"mpg":17.8,"hp":123},{"mpg":16.4,"hp":180},{"mpg":17.3,"hp":180},{"mpg":15.2,"hp":180},{"mpg":10.4,"hp":205},{"mpg":10.4,"hp":215},{"mpg":14.7,"hp":230},{"mpg":32.4,"hp":66},{"mpg":30.4,"hp":52},{"mpg":33.9,"hp":65},{"mpg":21.5,"hp":97},{"mpg":15.5,"hp":150},{"mpg":15.2,"hp":150},{"mpg":13.3,"hp":245},{"mpg":19.2,"hp":175},{"mpg":27.3,"hp":66},{"mpg":26,"hp":91},{"mpg":30.4,"hp":113},{"mpg":15.8,"hp":264},{"mpg":19.7,"hp":175},{"mpg":15,"hp":335},{"mpg":21.4,"hp":109}]
```

I want to plot this data as svg circles on two different x-axes (and thus scales) like this:

[image: axes]

*Furthermore,* I'd love it if the data were 'linked' in some way by a 'key' whereby if I hover over a point on one axis, the same point on the other axis is illuminated, highlighted, enlarged, etc. Any guidance on which approach to take would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>

<style>
  body {
    padding: 50px;
  }
  .point {
       transition: .5s;
   }
</style>

<title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.js'></script>
<script>
let data = [{"mpg":21,"hp":110},{"mpg":21,"hp":110},{"mpg":22.8,"hp":93},{"mpg":21.4,"hp":110},{"mpg":18.7,"hp":175},{"mpg":18.1,"hp":105},{"mpg":14.3,"hp":245},{"mpg":24.4,"hp":62},{"mpg":22.8,"hp":95},{"mpg":19.2,"hp":123},{"mpg":17.8,"hp":123},{"mpg":16.4,"hp":180},{"mpg":17.3,"hp":180},{"mpg":15.2,"hp":180},{"mpg":10.4,"hp":205},{"mpg":10.4,"hp":215},{"mpg":14.7,"hp":230},{"mpg":32.4,"hp":66},{"mpg":30.4,"hp":52},{"mpg":33.9,"hp":65},{"mpg":21.5,"hp":97},{"mpg":15.5,"hp":150},{"mpg":15.2,"hp":150},{"mpg":13.3,"hp":245},{"mpg":19.2,"hp":175},{"mpg":27.3,"hp":66},{"mpg":26,"hp":91},{"mpg":30.4,"hp":113},{"mpg":15.8,"hp":264},{"mpg":19.7,"hp":175},{"mpg":15,"hp":335},{"mpg":21.4,"hp":109}]

//dimension will be either 'mpg' or 'hp' 
function plotData( data, dimension ) {
    let width  = 1000,
        height = 100;
    let svg = d3.select( "body" ).append( "svg" ).attr( "width", width ).attr( "height", height )
    let xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain( d3.extent( data, d => d[dimension] ))
        .range( [ 50, width-20 ] )
        // Add scales to axis

    let x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
                   .scale(xscale);


    //Append group and insert axis
    svg.append("g")
       .call(x_axis);


    //add the datapoints 
    svg.selectAll( ".point" ).data( data )
        .enter().append( "circle" )
            .attr( "class", ( d, i) => {
                return `point point-${i}`
            })
            .attr( "r", 10 )
            .attr( "fill", dimension === "mpg" ? "red" : "blue" )
            .attr( "cx", (d,i) => { return xscale( +d[dimension] )})
            .attr( "cy", height / 2 )
            .attr( "opacity", .5 )
            .on( "mouseover", (d,i) => {
                d3.selectAll( `.point-${i}` ).attr( "r", 15 )
            }) 
            .on( "mouseleave", (d,i) => {
                d3.selectAll( `.point-${i}` ).attr( "r", 10 )
            })
    svg.append( "text" )
            .attr( "x", 30 )
            .attr( "y", 30 )
            .text( dimension )            
}

plotData( data, "mpg" )
plotData( data, "hp" )

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'll let you play to get the scale labels right, but essentially you tie the data together with a unique class name in this line.

```
.attr( "class", (d,i) => { return `point point-${i}`}
```

Then, when you hover with d3, you use the d3.selectAll to grab the all points of that class name.

```
.on( "mouseover", (d,i) => {
    d3.selectAll( `.point-${i}` ).attr( "r", 15 )
})
```

Note there is no need for enter here. If the elements already exist on the page, you can edit the attributes directly. i.e.

```
d3.selectAll( `.point-${i}`).attr( "height", 100 ) // works if .point-i is already on the dom 

d3.selectAll( `.point-${i}`).enter().append( "circle" ).attr( "height", 100 ) // needed if not already on DOM
```

Note for overlapped points only the last one added will be accessible by hover.

Comment: Thanks, this was a very thorough and helpful explanation! I was working on a similar plotData function, but never would have thought to assign a different class to each point. Clever!